# How do I fix this javascript foreach bug?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list, object

I have an object in the form of

```
res = { 2019: 
[
{id: 1, points: 435},
{id: 830, points: 230},
...
]
}
```

and an array seasons which is just a bunch of years => ["2015","2016",..."2019"]

```
seasons.forEach(season => {
     res[season].forEach(item => {
     console.log(item);
   });
});
```

The snipped above logs each result correctly however I still get this error: **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined**

Comment: Are you sure every `res[season]` is defined? Tried something like `(res[season] || []).forEach(...)`?

Comment: Well the error is pretty clear, you're trying to call `forEach` on something that's undefined. There's 2 places where trying a `forEach`, you checked them yet?

Comment: I tried res[2019] and res["2019"] still the same outcome. With a regular for loop 
    temp[2019][i] i get temp[2019].length is not defined

Comment: A simple check does the trick weirdly. Even though res contains every season explicitly from another part of my code.

Comment: `Unhandled Rejection` if you are using some async methods are you making sure you are waiting til the data is actually retrieved

Comment: do `Object.keys(res)` to see if the seasons array matches the keys array, you should not be using an if, if the records match

Comment: Use this before your loops

`const keys = Object.keys(res);
const seasons = ["2019", "2015" ]
if (keys.sort().join('') === seasons.sort().join('')) {
  console.log('match')
}  `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to easily solve this. Simply add a question mark before the nested `forEach`, like this:

```js
seasons.forEach(season => {
     res[season]?.forEach(item => {
     console.log(item);
   });
});
```

Note: As mentioned in the compatibility section of the linked doc, optional chaining is not yet supported by all browsers, so you might want to use a transpiler (like Babel)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that this method even existed.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes your object can be `undefined` so you should verify if the key exist:

```js
const ob = res = {
  2015: [{
      id: 1,
      points: 435
    },
    {
      id: 830,
      points: 230
    },
  ],
  2019: [{
      id: 1,
      points: 435
    },
    {
      id: 830,
      points: 230
    },
  ]
}

const seasons = ["2015", "2016", "2019"]

seasons.forEach(season => {
  if (res[season]) {

    res[season].forEach(item => {
      console.log(item);
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works strangely. I have some code above that explicitly maps one object containing many years to res and logged it without a problem, but without doing this check I would get the error. Still not sure why as it only contains the years that are already in seasons.